# How to receive imei from gps tracker

Tags: gps, imei, tracker, nmea

I found out many kind of gps trackers use $gprmc method of NMEA standard to send information to server but I don't know how they send IMEI (or id) to server yet.(there isn't IMEI parameter in NMEA) Could you please help me about that?

Answer (score 0):

More often they append IMEI or the device ID before the GPRMC sentence and additional data after this sentence. This method increases overall traffic but allows to send these messages using the UDP protocol.